# Openshift Tomcat 7 (JBoss EWS 2.0) cartridge, WAR file, Websockets

Tags: tomcat, websocket, openshift, war

I've been using OpenShift (Tomcat 7 (JBoss EWS 2.0) cartridge, with WAR file). I have the inconvenient that my project work perfectly on localhost... But when I use Websocket like "ws://app.rhcloud.com:8000/project/webSocket."

I got this message --> "failed: Error in connection establishment: net::ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT"

So I would like to know if I have to use bind port or another configuration in the application.

Thank You!!!

Answer (score 0):

Please refer to [this diagram](https://developers.openshift.com/managing-your-applications/port-binding-routing.html) which describes which port you can bind to with your application, and which ports are available to be accessed from the internet, which are:

1. HTTP - Port 80
2. HTTPS - Port 443
3. WS - Port 8000
4. WSS - Port 8443

You will need to make sure that your application is listening for websockets on your internal ip address on port 8080, the same as your web application.  I am unsure if OpenShift Online's version of Tomcat supports websocket upgrade, you might try running it on JBoss EAP or WildFly instead.